# Why check_icmp plugin from centreon isn't working?

Tags: segmentation-fault, nagios, plugin

I am trying to create a custom command in centreon like

```
 $USER1$/check_icmp -H $HOSTADDRESS$
```

however before that I just want to test this plugin (that comes with centreon) in my console. For that I write

```
 ./check_icmp 127.0.0.1
```

and, for some reason I have a **Segmentation fault** error.

However yesterday I have tried this command and got

```
./check_icmp 127.0.0.1
OK - 127.0.0.1 rta 0.033ms lost 0%|rta=0.033ms;200.000;500.000;0; 
rtmax=0.054ms;;;; rtmin=0.023ms;;;; pl=0%;40;80;0;100
```

When I screen my plugins in centreon they appear in red for some reason (maybe due to the s flag)

[image]

What might be wrong?

Comment: The syntax in the first line has a `-H` that you're not showing in the remaining examples; is that the issue?

Comment: No, I am not using -H right now. Just showed it as an example of centreon command. The only syntax I used was ./check_icmp 127.0.0.1 and it worked. I just don't understand what that segmentation fault error means? I cannot find a clear answer elsewhere..